# Not getting all results from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Can anybody help me with the issue I'm seeing? For some reason when I run my page, I get my drop down lists to populate the data, however the first item in my database, per each SQL query, doesn't get populated.

For example, my database table is:

**Category**

```
1  Books
2  Clothing
3  Toys
4  Household Items
```

my first query -

```
SELECT Category FROM ProductCategories
```

my drop down list gets populated with

```
Clothing
Toys
Household Items
```

I have 2 other drop down lists I'm populating and those are doing the same thing. Once I get this figured out, I'll try to figure out the other problem I'm having with inserting the data in the database.

Thank you!

```
public partial class InsertItems : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand populateList;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LakerBids"].ConnectionString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        populateList = new SqlCommand("USE LakerBids SELECT Category FROM ProductCategories;" +
                                "USE LakerBids SELECT SubCategory FROM ProductSubCategories;" +
                              "USE LakerBids SELECT LName FROM Users", connection);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                reader = populateList.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    pcategory.DataSource = reader;
                    pcategory.DataValueField = "Category";
                    pcategory.DataBind();
                }

                reader.NextResult();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    psubcategory.DataSource = reader;
                    psubcategory.DataValueField = "SubCategory";
                    psubcategory.DataBind();
                }

                reader.NextResult();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    user.DataSource = reader;
                    user.DataValueField = "LName";
                    user.DataBind();
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void AddItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand insertData;

            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LakerBids"].ConnectionString;
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            insertData = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, ProductDesc, CategoryID, SubCatID, StatusID, UserID, ReservePrice, AuctionLength, BidID)" +
            "VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductDesc, @CategoryID, @SubCatID, 1, @UserID, @ReservePrice, @AuctionLength, NULL)", connection);

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            insertData.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value = pname.Text;

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@ProductDesc", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
            insertData.Parameters["@ProductDesc"].Value = pdesc.Text;

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            insertData.Parameters["@CategoryID"].Value = pcategory.SelectedIndex;

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@SubCatID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            insertData.Parameters["@SubCatID"].Value = psubcategory.SelectedIndex;

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@UserID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            insertData.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = user.SelectedIndex + 2;

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@ReservePrice", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money);
            insertData.Parameters["@ReservePrice"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(reserveprice.Text);

            insertData.Parameters.Add("@AuctionLength", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            insertData.Parameters["@AuctionLength"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(auctionlength.Text);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                insertData.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("Categories.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                dberror.Text = error.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting one row per query??

Comment: I can give you a suggestion. You'd better separate your logic into several layers. At least two. First is a dal where you make a query to database and convert the result into the in memory objects and then populate your UI. With your code layout it is really difficult to track down the bugs. Not only this one but in general.

Comment: why are you combining those 3 selects ? try seperating them, its more manageable.
so for your categories, just use "USE LakerBids SELECT Category FROM ProductCategories;""

Comment: First of all - don't put an `USE LakerBids` into each of your SQL statement; by means of the connection string, you have already picke which database to use. And second of all - don't bind a `SqlDataReader` to a dropdown list - that'll create an open connection for the whole time.... **read** the data from the data reader into a `List<Category>` and then bind **that** to your drop down list ...

Comment: reader.Read() is probably consuming your first entry. If you remove while loops, thing might actually work. **BUT** you should transfer data from reader to List<> or DataSet and bind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use a DataSet or populate business entities within a collection and then bind to the collection.

```
List<Category> cats = new List<Category>();

while (reader.Read()) 
{ 
   Category cat = new Category();

   // fill properties from DataReader
   cats.Add(cat);
} 

pcategory.DataSource = cats; 
pcategory.DataValueField = "Category"; 
pcategory.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sab0tr0n, I suspect one of two things are happening.

1) If you are saying the first item does not appear AFTER you do some kind of "Add Category" action, then it might be that the dropdown is populated BEFORE the insert completes. Meaning, you need to requery after allowing the insert to be committed to the database.

OR

2) Put a breakpoint on this line:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LakerBids"].ConnectionString;
```

Then confirm the connectionString is to the correct database. I've seen old config files that point to test or staging databases cause this kind of confusion.

Good luck. If these aren't the answer, maybe simplify your example to us or elaborate on exactly what you do with your application and when you see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "reader.read()" statement in each block is actually reading the first row of data, so when you set the DataSource, the first row has already been read. Try taking it out

You should use "while (reader.Read())" if you want to iterate over each result, not bind the resulset in one step.

That being said, the comments about using a Dataset, seperating logic, etc., are valid